# $q$-Mellin transform and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. And consider its Mellin transform $M(f)(s)$ given by

$$M(f)(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x, $$

Let $M_q(f)$ denote the $q$-Mellin transform of $f$, that is, the Riemann sum in the partition $[q^{k+1},q^{k}]$, where $0<q<1$, given by

$$M_q(f)(s)=(1-q)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f(q^k)q^{ks},$$

We will have as $q$ goes to $1$,pointwise convergence holds. Define $F(t)=M(f)(\sigma+it)$ and $F_q(t)=M_q(f)(\sigma+it)$. The question is, does $F_q$ converges uniformly to $F$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$?

EDIT:I'm interested in knowing if $M_q(f)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+it\right)$ can be zero or not in $(-\infty,\infty)$ . If you know a different argument to see the behaviour of the zeroes will be appreciated.

THANK YOU!